# Компонент OnePage Virtuemart 3

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

http://your-webmasters.com/demo/brasplast/
Подскажите, как задать каждому способу доставки свой логотип OnePage Virtuemart 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно загрузить логотип в соответствующий каталог и только после этого в выпадающем списке в настройках доставки будет доступен вариант логотипа.